# Proper Flow under Kitchen Sink connected to Disposal

Tags: kitchens, sink, mold, p-trap, disposal

[image]

Hi all, I really appreciated the feedback on my last post pertaining to bathroom sink p-trap, so I thought I'd try to get some advice on this situation. It's been like this since we've moved in, (granted, the sink/downpipe and disposal are both new, but pipe config is basically the same.

I haven't noticed smells coming back up, but it seems odd to have the p-trap shaped like a U, especially if solids from disposal are trying to force upward  ... (there is a white pipe extension that is difficult to see at this angle.

Disregard the blue rag for now, there was a small leak with new faucet soap dispenser, and now mold has formed underneath that base piece of plywood on the original particle board... so removing those damaged materials will be a fun project tomorrow... [smh]. Might make a separate post about that if it becomes a more difficult task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So long as there is no more than 4" from the bottom of the outlet pipe to the top of the lower part of the P, it's acceptable.

Mind you, it does seem like someone didn't know that they can and should trim excess length from the male parts of sliding drain joints, as there appears to be enough vertical space available on both the disposal and sink to slide the whole mess up and lose the white part. But if the white part is 2 inches or less it's likely fine (minimum trap depth is 2" - max except for special circumstances is 4" so most stock traps are 2")

You are not getting gas, and if you are not getting clogs, might want to leave well enough alone.